React redux, component re-rendering
I have a react functional component, I want the component to re-render when the state coming from the store is updated.
I want the component to re-render when the value of logoPic variable is updated. The value is coming from the redux store(fetched using useSelector hook).
const { user: { downloadLink, bucketName, timeStamp, logoPic, organizationName, logoName, }, } = useSelector((state) => state.loginReducer);

Did you try with useEffect ? useEffect(() => {}, [logoPic]);

A component subscribed to a redux store re-renders when there is an update to the store and the value returned from the selector is updated.
Currently you are subscribing to (state) => state.loginReducer, so whenever loginReducer updates, the component rerenders.
Update your selector to:
const logoPic = useSelector((state) => state.loginReducer.user.logoPic);


I am directly not updating logoPic to the store, I send it through a payload from a different component, later on the logoPic is stored in the store(from the API response) when we login the next time.
